# Key technique to find the nature of root(s)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

What is the key technique to be used to solve these types of problems?

Comment: I'd solve it by eliminating the options....
    for eg, take c2 as 0, so c0 = 1 & c1 = -2. you'll find root as 0.5, thereby removing the options B & D.
    Now take c1 as 0 & c0 as -1 c2 as 3.
    so you have roots +/- 1/3. so option C is removed too.

Answer (score 2):

Probably using well-chosen values of the $C$'s to eliminate possibilities. For example, pick $C_2=0$. That eliminates possibilities (B), (C), and (D)! On to the next question.